# HTTPS Failing on Media in Magento

Tags: security, magento, ssl, https, media

I'm having a problem with a clients magento site that has https enabled on the secure pages,

The website it built heavily around static block content and on the https pages images are pulled from static blocks (over 400 of them) using the media insert in the static block {{media url="media/bla/bla/bob.png"}} these images are comign through as http://site.com/media/bla/bla/bob.png

its not realistic, and it wouldn't make any sense to go through and change all these links to direct links.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Roly!

You are suppose to use the `{{store url=""}}` or the `{{secure_base_url}}media/` in ur blocks

if ur not certain that ur page will be on HTTPS or HTTP the use first one if you know for sure that the request will be HTTPs use second one. (NOTE. Second is a system config path not the actual value that u'll put in the CMS block).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas media files are not subject to a fallback, and with the awareness that if the directory level for Magento changes w/r/t the webroot (e.g. `http://site.com/` vs. `http://site.com/magento/`) you can lead with the double-slash network location:

```
<img src="//media/bla/bob.png" />
```

Therefore, a search and replace against using the current data in `cms_block.content` is indicated.

I'll reiterate that this *is not* appropriate for skin assets due to the fallback.